# Retaining data in a named pipe after an incomplete read access

Tags: io-redirection, fifo

Prerequisites:

```
$ mkfifo pipe1
```

---

If several lines are put into *pipe1*

```
$ (echo line 1; echo line 2) > pipe1
```

all the lines can be read in another terminal by

```
$ cat pipe1
line 1
line 2
```

So far all right.

### But

if instead of the latter *cat* several partial reads are executed

```
$ head -n 1 pipe1; head -n 1 pipe1
line 1
```

then only the first line of the data piped into *pipe1* is returned (by the first *head -n 1*); the rest of the data seems to get lost, the second read access is hanging hence waiting for (new) data available in *pipe1*.

### How

to set up a named pipe and pipe contents to it in such a way that several consecutive partial reads are possible?

In other words, how to get this:

```
$ head -n 1 pipe1; head -n 1 pipe1
line 1
line 2
```

Comment: IIRC, but I may be wrong here, you can't close the pipe - this will flush the data. But `head` closes it. So you'll need a custom version of `head` that doesn't close it. Not very elegant. What are you trying to achieve with this? It sounds like an [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @dirk1 In the end I want to have a persistent FIFO queue: write arbitrary times to a file, read arbitrary times from the same file, data that is read disappears from the queue. Named pipes seemed to me like a solution for that. But as pointed out in the question, it does not work like expected by me.

Comment: Pipes won't work for this. See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118029/how-to-use-a-persistent-named-pipe-under-linux) for alternatives.